# Groking the parallel-matrix

Tags: gitlab-ci

This seems to be a mis-use of the new Parallel Matrix feature in GitLab 13.3 (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallel-matrix-jobs)

I have a collection of parallel jobs for a set of services: `build` (docker image), `test`, `release`, `delete`.... and the code-base is created so that each parallel service is in a separate sub-directory.

This way I can have a common template:

```
variables:
  IMAGE_NAME: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$LOCATION

.build-template:
  script:
    - docker build --tag $IMAGE_NAME:$CI_PIPELINE_ID-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG --tag $IMAGE_NAME:latest $LOCATION
  stage: build
  when: manual
```

then multiple build jobs:

```
build-alpha:
  extends: .build-template
  variables:
    LOCATION: alpha

build-beta:
  extends: .build-template
  variables:
    LOCATION: beta
```

.... and repeat as needed.

I can then do the same thing for `test`, `release`, and `delete` jobs: a common template that takes just the one variable to distinguish the service.

### Matrix to the rescue?

It would seem to me that

```
variables:
  IMAGE_NAME: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$NOTEBOOK

build-services:
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - LOCATION: alpha
      - LOCATION: beta
  script:
    - docker build --tag $IMAGE_NAME:$CI_PIPELINE_ID-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG --tag $IMAGE_NAME:latest $LOCATION
  stage: build
  when: manual
```

would be an *ideal* candidate for this `matrix` form.... but apparently `matrix` requires **two** variables.

Has anyone got a good solution for this multiple-parallel jobs problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> would be an ideal candidate for this matrix form.... but apparently matrix requires two variables.

Not anymore.

See [GitLab 13.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/10/22/gitlab-13-5-released/#allow-one-dimensional-parallel-matrices) (October 2020)

> ### Allow one dimensional parallel matrices
>
> Previously, the `parallel: matrix` keyword, which runs a matrix of jobs in parallel, only accepted two-dimensional matrix arrays. This was limiting if you wanted to specify your own array of values for certain jobs.
>
> In this release, you now have more flexibility to run your jobs the way that works best for your development workflow.
> You can run a parallel matrix of jobs in a one-dimensional array, making your pipeline configuration much simpler. Thanks [Turo Soisenniemi](https://gitlab.com/Turmio) for your amazing contribution!
>
> Here’s a basic example of this in practice that will run 3 test jobs for different versions of Node.js, but you can apply this approach to your specific use cases and easily add or remove jobs in your pipeline as well:
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_5/simple-parallel-matrices-example.png -- One dimensional matrices example]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallel-matrix-jobs) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/26362).

---

And with [GitLab 13.10](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/03/22/gitlab-13-10-released/#use-parallel-matrix-with-trigger-jobs) (March 2021)

> ### Use 'parallel: matrix' with trigger jobs
>
> You can use the `parallel: matrix` keywords to run jobs multiple times in parallel, using different variable values for each instance of the job.
>
> Unfortunately, you could not use it with trigger jobs.
>
> In this release, we’ve expanded the parallel matrix feature to support trigger jobs as well, so you can now run multiple downstream pipelines (child or multi-project pipelines) in parallel using different variables value for each downstream pipeline.
> This lets you configure CI/CD pipelines that are faster and more flexible.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_10/parallel.png -- Use 'parallel: matrix' with trigger jobs]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#parallel-matrix-trigger-jobs) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/270957).

---

Documentation: "[Run a matrix of parallel trigger jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#run-a-matrix-of-parallel-trigger-jobs)"

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#run-a-matrix-of-parallel-trigger-jobs

Comment: @wasserholz Thank you. I have included the link in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/241127) by Gitlab.

There is a workaround using a "dummy" value for the second value (I'm working with Gitlab 13.3.1).

For your example, it gives this :

```
parallel:
  matrix:
    - LOCATION: ['alpha', 'beta']
      DUMMY: 'dummy'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
parallel:
  matrix:
    - LOCATION: [alpha, beta]
```